# Boto s3 filter to get prefix smaller than a given prefix

Tags: amazon-s3, python-3.7, boto, minio

I've an s3 storage which stores the files as such

```
2021/05/06/folder1/file.ext
2022/05/06/folder2/file.ext
2022/06/06/folder3/file.ext
```

is there a way to get all object paths which have prefix lesser than a given date , say '2022/05/07' which will return the ist 2 files

I cant find any filter as such, only solution I've currently is to brute force and check for every prefix smaller than the one given

Comment: There is no such option.  You'll need to list all objects, and once you find an object at or above the target prefix, stop your enumeration.

Comment: If you are using python, you should be able to sort these, you could probably do something along the lines of `stuff = sorted(list_of_objects)` and then to get the first two you could do `print(stuff[:2])`